# mysql delete record group by excluding group by

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
| id | EAN | supplier_code |
|0001|11111|         aaaaaa|
|0002|22222|         aaaaaa|
|0003|33333|         bbbbbb|
|0004|33333|         cccccc|
|0005|11111|         aaaaaa|
```

I must delete ID's like 3 and 4 because they are dirty data.
How do I write a select to find them?

something like this

```
SELECT id, EAN, supplier_code, COUNT( id ) AS NumDuplicati
FROM table
WHERE supplier_code <>  ""
GROUP BY EAN
HAVING NumDuplicati >1
```

But I mustn't delete ID's like 1 and 5...

Comment: so ID's 0003 & 0004 need to go because they have different supplier codes for the same EAN?

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED: not sure if you can distinct in the having like this...

```
delete from yourTable where EAN in (
Select EAN
FROM yourTable
Group by EAN
having count(distinct supplier_Code ) > 1)
```

Comment: [It didn't work before MySQL 4.0.31 / 4.1.1](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=299)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply
this query destroys my server, and go timeout, do you know why?